# Multiple DND rules for different schedules

Tags: samsung, do-not-disturb

I am looking to have two DND schedules with two different rules as follows:

> 1. From 12:00 AM till 7:00 am - No sound for any notification from any application but calls are allowed for everybody.
> 2. From 7:00 AM till I stop - No sound, no calls are allowed except for the calls from Favorites contact.

The second one I already have successfully running on my phone but I find no way to have both the schedules running on one phone.

Android gives option to define only one set of DND rule and all the schedules will follow the same rules set.

I am looking for something where I can have two different rule set for two schedules.

As far as I can see and search it is not possible with Android default, or is it in any way?

Or, is there any app which can allow me to do this specific thing? Paid app will also work.

Comment: Try [tag:automation]

Comment: Please ask for any software recommendations on Software Recommendations SE, as they are off-topic here. See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Found an amazing in-built way to achieve that.

There is something called `Modes and Routines` in android where you will find already built `Modes`, you can create your own ones.

I modified the existing `Mode` sleep.

This is an amazing feature which allows you to customize almost everything that you want to achieve during certain modes like sleeping, driving etc.

These modes can be made auto activate by defining the timings.

So I modified the `Sleep` mode to be activated during certain time period and during that mode I defined to switch off the wifi as well as the mobile data.

And these modes work independent of do not disturb.
So now I have a sleep mode running during I sleep which only disable internet and then I have DND running during 7-10 am.

This works like a charm without any external app or any complicated developers' logic building!

This is how my `Sleep` mode settings look like

[image]

Comment: Just a note that "Modes and Routines" is Samsung's customization. Other manufacturers may use a different name or not having it at all.